# Creating A Bar chart in d3.js from an JSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this JSON data

```
{"1960":"133.55501327769","1961":"134.159118941963","1962":"134.857912280869","1963":"134.504575565342","1964":"134.105211273476","1965":"133.569625896451","1966":"132.675635192775","1967":"131.665502129354","1968":"129.190980115918","1969":"126.736756382819","1970":"124.382808900193","1971":"122.133431342027","1972":"120.020185557559","1973":"118.087531093609","1974":"116.132988067096","1975":"114.100918174437","1976":"111.980005447216","1977":"109.783821762662","1978":"106.033489239906","1979":"102.341720681455","1980":"98.7390023274647","1981":"95.2412508672801","1982":"91.7911923993222","1983":"88.0011769487606","1984":"84.2072557839419","1985":"80.3593225600132","1986":"76.4415956498419","1987":"72.5145803648751","1988":"71.1706639452677","1989":"69.8887679924858","1990":"69.0044133814268","1991":"67.7559924352118","1992":"66.9284506867798","1993":"64.9489678572737","1994":"62.9227777228154","1995":"60.7070695260477","1996":"58.5966308804751","1997":"56.4401276304142","1998":"55.5315395528949","1999":"54.6587808352011","2000":"53.8314102398679","2001":"52.9015276443892","2002":"51.9907926813042","2003":"51.5228563035101","2004":"51.1032496482833","2005":"50.7325902239383","2006":"50.3291352282938","2007":"49.9998514069402","2008":"49.8870459355469","2009":"49.7812066054555","2010":"49.6729747116906","2011":"49.5360469363113","2012":"49.3837446924523","2013":"48.7965576984378","2014":"48.1964180547578","2015":"47.5501940499984","Country Name":"Arab World","Country Code":"ARB","Indicator Name":"Adolescent fertility rate (births per 1,000 women ages 15-19)","Indicator Code":"SP.ADO.TFRT","":""}
```

which I convert from CSV to JS object.

How do I build a bar chart with d3.js where the  key is the X axis and the values are the Y axis?

here's what I came up with

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


// set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);


// add the SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.csv, "http://localhost:8000/HNP_Data.csv")
  .defer(d3.csv, "http://localhost:8000/HNP_Series.csv")
  .await(analyze);

 var dataToVis; 
 var array = []


  function analyze(error,data,series) {
    dataToVis = data[2];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataToVis));

    for (var key in dataToVis) {
        if(!isNaN(key) && key.length >0) {
            var p = new Object;
            p.year = key;
            p.frequency = p(dataToVis[key]);
            array.push(p);
        }
    }

    array.forEach(function(d){
        d.year = d.year;
        d.frequency = +d.frequency;
    });

      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  // add axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");


  // Add bar chart
  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(array)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
 }
```

but I end up with this error.

```
Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".
Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".
```

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: @RaxWeber I have updated my question

Comment: @Petar the code I posted has parseFloat